# Facebook Chat API - login with email

Tags: c#, .net, facebook, authentication

I am creating a Facebook chat client. I've got it working through agsXMPP library, however I must login with user ID (user@chat.facebook.com). Is there a way to get user ID from user login email or just log in a special way with user email?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to log into the wrong server; that sounds like how users would log into chat directly with username and password.
To do this in your app, you need to use the API: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/chat/ - this involves sending a user to an auth dialog, where they approve your app to access their chat, and you get back an access token you can use to log into chat as the user

Comment: No, in that case you'd need to use the other (username/password) method for chat, but that only works for users that have created a username, and you'd need them to specify their username when logging in, which they may not actually know